# Get row numbers of rows matching a condition in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array like:

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

I want to check if the second element == 2.

I know I can do this:

```
>>> a[:,1]==2
array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

returning booleans. My question is, how do I get the row numbers of the rows where the condition is true? In this example I would want to get back `array([0, 3])` because the 0th and 3rd rows match the condition second element == 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to return the indices:

```
In [79]:

np.where(a[:,1]==2)
Out[79]:
(array([0, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I used, which provides only the row numbers:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1]])

row_locator = a[:,1]==2

row_values = []

for x in range(0, len(a)):
    if row_locator[x]:
        row_values.append(x)

print(row_values)

>>>[0, 3]
```