# Finding a matching row in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Using numpy, I have a matrix called `points`.

```
   points
=> matrix([[0, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 3],
        [4, 6],
        [0, 7],
        [0, 3]])
```

If I have the tuple `(1, 3)`, I want to find the row in `points` that matches these numbers (in this case, the row index is 2).

I tried using np.where:

```
np.where(points == (1, 3))
=> (array([2, 2, 5]), array([0, 1, 1]))
```

What is the meaning of this output? Can it be used to find the row where `(1, 3)` occurs?

Comment: Divakar gave a nice answer, but you could also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145996/get-row-numbers-of-rows-matching-a-condition-in-numpy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were just needed to look for [`ALL matches`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along each row, like so -

```
np.where((a==(1,3)).all(axis=1))[0]
```

Steps involved using given sample -

```
In [17]: a # Input matrix
Out[17]: 
matrix([[0, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 3],
        [4, 6],
        [0, 7],
        [0, 3]])

In [18]: (a==(1,3)) # Matrix of broadcasted matches
Out[18]: 
matrix([[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [19]: (a==(1,3)).all(axis=1) # Look for ALL matches along each row
Out[19]: 
matrix([[False],
        [False],
        [ True],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False]], dtype=bool)

In [20]: np.where((a==(1,3)).all(1))[0] # Use np.where to get row indices
Out[20]: array([2])
```