# numpy.extract() outcome different than expected

Tags: python, numpy, extract

For below array np.extract produces [0,0] outcome while for other arrays it gives the number of rows for which meet the condition. Therefore for this one I'd expect [3,6] as the outcome.

Can you please take a look at find out which part is failing?

```
print(type(perm_list))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(perm_list.shape)
(8, 5)
print(perm_list)
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 7 0 0 0]
 [2 6 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 6 2 0 0]
 [4 7 0 0 0]]

perm_list_mask = np.extract(perm_list[:, 2] == 2, perm_list)
print(perm_list_mask)
[0 0]
```

Here is another array I use in my script and it works seamlessly:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1,  2, 3], [4,  5,  6,  7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [8,  10,  4, 3], [8,  1,  5, 5]])

b = np.extract(a[:, 0] == 8, a)
print(b)
[2 3 4]
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(perm_list[:, 2] == 2)`?

Comment: `extract` returns an array of *values* from the original array which satisfy a condition. If any, you should expect to get `[2, 2]`. If you want the row numbers `[3, 6]` I think you need a different method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get row numbers of rows matching a condition in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145996/get-row-numbers-of-rows-matching-a-condition-in-numpy)

Comment: 'print(perm_list[:, 2] == 2)' returns '[False False False  True False False  True False]'  as expected.

Comment: Who or what prompted you to use `extract`?  It isn't a commonly used function (I had to look it up).  And its docs says it returns 'elements' or 'values' (not indices).  In your case there's the added complication of trying to apply a 1d condition to a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting [0,0] for an answer is because np.extract requires the array in the condition to be the same shape as the array passed into the second argument. perm_list[:, 2] is different shape than perm_list. The below corrects this and returns [2,2] as mkieger1 says. Below that is code that returns the answer you are looking for.

```
def p():
    perm_list = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[4,7,0,0,0],[2,6,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[2,6,2,0,0],[4,7,0,0,0]]) 
    perm_list_mask = np.extract(perm_list[:, 2] == 2, perm_list[:,2])
    print(perm_list_mask)


def pSolved():
    perm_list = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[4,7,0,0,0],[2,6,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[2,6,2,0,0],[4,7,0,0,0]]) 
    return np.where(perm_list[:, 2] == 2)
```

Output:

```
>>> p()
[2 2]
>>> pSolved()
(array([3, 6]),)
```

Comment: Do you know why np.extract() works for my 2nd array a? a[:, 0] has different shape than a and yet row index is returned by extract function.

Comment: If you share your 2nd array I’ll take a look. But if you look at help(np.extract) you’ll see the specification requires the same shape.

Comment: @pelamis22 The reason why you are getting the correct answer on 2nd array is coincidence. Extract is flattening your array and returning the values in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th positions, which are  2,3,4 and just so happen to match the row indexes containing an 8 in column 0. If you change the 4 in row 1 column 0 to say 15, your result will be 2,3,15 instead of 2,3,4

Comment: @pelamis22 an accepted answer and/or up arrow would be appreciated ;)